# Inquiry regarding surjective function

Tags: functions, proof-verification

We are required to determine if the function $f:\mathbf{R}\rightarrow A$ defined by $f(x)=\{y\in\mathbf{R}|y^2<x\}$is surjective where $A$ is the power set of $\mathbf{R}$

*Proof.* Assume that $f$ is *surjective* thus $\forall X\in A\exists a\in\mathbf{R}(f(a)=X)$, thus in particular for  $\{4\}=X\in A$ there is some  $a\in\mathbf{R}$  such that  $f(a)=\{y\in \mathbf{R}|y^2<a\}=X$, evidently $a\in R^{+}$ and thus $0\in f(a)$ but $0\not\in X$ implying that $f(a)\neq X$, thus by contradiction we can reason that $f$ is not *surjective*. $\blacksquare$

Is the above argument correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can appeal to Cantor's theorem, which says that no function from a set to its power set is surjective.  Alternately, you can find a subset of $\mathbf R$ that is not the image of any real.  All the image sets of $f$ are of the form $(-a,a)$ or the empty set, so show there is no $x$ such that $f(x)=[0,a)$

Comment: Yes your quite right it was a mistake the definition is as you have indicated